# Stop 0x0000007B on Intel US15W with PATA/IDE

Tags: windows-embedded-7

Usually when people get `STOP 0x0000007B`, it's caused by missing `AHCI/RAID` drivers. I've run into the opposite. My WES7 image boots perfectly from a system with AHCI/RAID, but when I try it on a system with an `Intel US15W` chipset, which is just Parallel ATA / IDE with no AHCI or RAID in sight, I don't get far.

As far as I understand, the drivers for IDE are always included in the base component. I've had a look in the registry and it looks alright. The `ATAPI` driver has `Start = 0`.

I tried running `IBW` on the target, and that works perfectly. It does look like the BCD's differ from my generalized image to the one created by IBW, but seeing that it works on a system with AHCI it seems that this shouldn't be the issue. I've also checked what drivers IBW adds, and it doesn't include anything I don't already have in my image or add with DISM before applying the image.

What else could be going on here?

Update: Just took my exact same answer file and installed it directly on the target system instead of in a Hyper-V vm. Boots just fine, even after sysprep. So something definitely differs. Any idea where to look? Any docs on what exactly goes on during boot in Windows?

Comment: You are trying to boot the same image on both devices?

Comment: @Ramhound I have a generic image that I setup on Hyper-V, generalize and capture. Then I write that to whatever storage the target has and throw on some hardware specific drivers using DISM.

Comment: You have verified that on the image that does not have AHCI/RAID support that the driver is being loaded?

Comment: @Ramhound Just checked, it shows `atapi.sys`, `pciide.sys` and `msahci.sys` (left that in, shouldn't matter I hope). Are there any other drivers that might be related?

Comment: On VMware, there’s an additional driver called `intelide`. Seeing how yours is also an Intel chipset, it might be required there, too.

Comment: @DanielB Had a look and it seems that one is included as well. Along with amdide, cmdide, iaStorV, msahci and viaide.